# Combining two animated plot into one GIF/MP4

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have created two animated time series charts based on the same dataset.  One is a line chart showing the trend in the total, and one is a bar chart showing the top 5 sub-groups.  I want to see if I can combine these into one time series animation, either side by side or with the line chart as a small inset.

I've built the separate animations, but its unclear to me if I can combine them, or if I need to create a new image with each frame having the inset, and then animate that.

Here's a minimal example dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Year = c(rep(1988, 5), rep(1989, 5), rep(1990, 5)),
  Total = c(rep(1000, 5), rep(1100, 5), rep(1200, 5),
  SubGroup = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "B", "A", "C", "D", E", "B", "C", "A", "E", "D"),
  Amount = c(200, 180, 100, 80, 60, 210, 200, 150, 100, 80, 250, 240, 200, 150, 110)
)
```

Here's my code for the top 5 barchart animation:

```
# generate top 5 ranking by year

anim_table <- data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Year) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    rank = min_rank(-Amount) * 1,
    Value_rel = Amount / Amount[rank == 1],
    Value_lbl = paste0(" ", Amount)
  ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(rank <= 5) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(Year, rank)

# create static barchart

p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(anim_table, aes(rank)) +
  ggplot2::geom_tile(aes(
    y = Amount / 2,
    height = Amount,
    width = 0.9,
    fill = "blue"
  ), alpha = 0.8, color = NA) +
  ggplot2::geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = paste(SubGroup, " ")), size = 12, vjust = 0.2, hjust = 1) +
  ggplot2::geom_text(aes(y = Amount, label = Value_lbl, hjust = 0)) +
  ggplot2::coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_reverse() +
  ggplot2::guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +
  ggplot2::labs(
    title = "{closest_state}", x = "", y = "Amount",
    caption = "Source:  whatever"
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme(
    plot.title = element_text(color = "darkblue", face = "bold", hjust = 0, size = 30),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 1, 16, "cm")
  ) +
# animate over Years
  gganimate::transition_states(Year, transition_length = 4, state_length = 1) +
  gganimate::ease_aes("cubic-in") 

gganimate::animate(p1, 200, fps = 5, duration = 100, width = 2000, height = 1200, renderer = gifski_renderer("anim1.gif"))
```

And here is the code for my simple animated line chart:

```
p2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(
  hc_total,
  aes(Year, Total)
) +
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
  ggplot2::scale_color_viridis_d() +
  ggplot2::labs(x = "Year", y = "Total") +
  gganimate::transition_reveal(Year)

gganimate::animate(p2, 200, fps = 5, duration = 100, width = 2000, height = 1200, renderer = gifski_renderer("anim2.gif"))
```

Looking to work out how to combine these two animations into a single animation either side by side or with the line chart as an inset.

Comment: You can do that with ImageMagick. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am working on a Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with ImageMagick. The two GIFs must have the same number of frames and preferably the same size.

For Windows, I wrote this R function which runs ImageMagick:

```
appendGIFs <- function(gif1, gif2, gifout, vertically=FALSE, 
                        delay=20, convert = "C:/PortableApps/ImageMagick/convert"){
  command <- sprintf("%s ( %s -coalesce -set page %s+0+0 -coalesce ) null: ( %s -coalesce ) -gravity %s -layers composite -set delay %d -loop 0 %s", 
                     convert, gif1, ifelse(vertically, "%[w]x%[fx:h*2]", "%[fx:w*2]x%[h]"), 
                     gif2, ifelse(vertically, "south", "east"),  delay, gifout)
  system(command) 
}
```

Here, `gif1` is the path to the first GIF, `gif2` is the path to the second GIF,  `gifout` is the name of the output GIF, `convert` is the path to the `convert` executable of ImageMagick (may be you can set `convert = "magick convert"` if ImageMagick is in your path).

For Linux, here is the command to run in order to append side by side:

```
convert file1.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\( file2.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\) \\
          +append -channel A -evaluate set 0 +channel \\
          file1.gif -coalesce -delete 0 \\
          null: \\( file2.gif -coalesce \\) \\
          -gravity East -layers Composite output.gif
```

To append vertically:

```
convert file1.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\( file2.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\) \\
          -append -channel A -evaluate set 0 +channel \\
          file1.gif -coalesce -delete 0 \\
          null: \\( file2.gif -coalesce \\) \\
          -gravity South -layers Composite output.gif
```

For Mac, I don't know (I would try the Linux way).

## EDIT

The following should work on any OS.

```
appendGIFs <- function(gif1, gif2, gifout="result.gif", vertically=FALSE, 
                       delay=20, convert = "C:/PortableApps/ImageMagick/convert"){
  currentdir <- getwd()
  on.exit(setwd(currentdir))
  tmpdir <- tempdir()
  invisible(file.remove(list.files(tmpdir, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.gif$")))
  file.copy(gif1, to = file.path(tmpdir, "gif1.gif"))
  file.copy(gif2, to = file.path(tmpdir, "gif2.gif"))
  setwd(tmpdir)
  command <- sprintf("%s gif1.gif -coalesce gif1-%%05d.gif", convert)
  system(command)
  command <- sprintf("%s gif2.gif -coalesce gif2-%%05d.gif", convert)
  system(command)
  nframes <- length(list.files(tmpdir, pattern = "^gif1-.*gif$"))
  for(i in 1:nframes){
    command <- sprintf("%s gif1-%05d.gif gif2-%05d.gif %sappend gif-%05d.gif", 
                       convert, i-1, i-1, ifelse(vertically, "-", "+"), i)
    system(command)
  }
  command <- sprintf("%s -loop 0 -delay %d gif-*.gif result.gif", convert, delay)
  system(command)
  file.copy("result.gif", file.path(currentdir, gifout), overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Looks like I need to adjust the syntax somewhat for it to work on a Mac - I'll play around and report back!  Thanks!

Comment: This worked great - sorry for the delay in responding.  Thanks so much!